# Is there a difference between induction in Peano Arithmetic and Presburger Arithmetic?

Tags: logic, arithmetic, incompleteness, peano-axioms, presburger-arithmetic

Following [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1118373/why-is-it-impossible-to-define-multiplication-in-presburger-arithmetic-yet-possi) I still do not get clearly the difference between defining exponentiation in PA but impossiblity of recursively define multiplication in Presburger Arithmetics

I was thinking one can do things like define base case Multi(x, y, z) where y is 0 and z is 0, and then define Multi(x,y,z) being there exist z which is the sum of z2 from Multi(x, y2, z2) and y, where y2 is the predecessor of y?

Apparently for some reason this is not allowed? I assume this is to do with: "Presburger arithmetic is not strong enough to quantify over sequences", but why? what is the reason? is it because the induction schema is different between the two arithmetics?

Comment: A proposition is a closed form in the language of the system. You cannot define a proposition recursively, because that is not a closed formula in the language of the system. You can define exponentiation in Peano because you can apply numerical tricks - addition and multiplication together gives you enough complexity.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference in induction between Peano arithmetic and Presburger arithmetic. In fact, there is only one difference between Peano arithmetic and Presburger arithmetic which is:

Peano arithmetic includes both *addition* and *multiplication*, while Presburger arithmetic only includes *addition*.

Once you include both addition and multiplication, you can represent any primitive recursive function (such as exponentiation) in Peano arithmetic. See proof here: http://www.cs.cornell.edu/courses/cs4860/2009sp/lec-22.pdf

The way you are defining multiplication is recursively as follows:

$$M(x,0) = 0$$
$$M(x, S(y)) = M(x, y) + x$$

That does not mean that a multiplication function with these properties exists. In Peano arithmetic, we *assume* it exists while in Presburger there is no such assumption. For a more detailed explanation on why such a definition doesn't work see my answer to a similar question: [Why is it impossible to define multiplication in Presburger arithmetic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/346857/why-is-it-impossible-to-define-multiplication-in-presburger-arithmetic/1621371#1621371)

Comment: Perhaps one could say the same thing in a different way: the only difference between induction in PA and induction in Presberger arithmetic is that induction in PA applies to all formulas with addition and/or multiplication, while in Presberger arithmetic induction only applies to formulas that do not have multiplication, because all formulas in Presberger arithmetic are required to be in terms of addition only.